# Identical for all elements, but not identical vectors?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two vectors, one from sqldf() and another from unique(). They should be identical. When I use a for loop to inspect each element, the two vectors are the same, but identical() on the two vectors returns FALSE. Any ideas?

```
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite") 
options(gsubfn.engine = "R") 
library(sqldf)
url <-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv"
download.file(url, destfile = "CommunitySurvey.csv")
acs <- read.table("CommunitySurvey.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
query <- as.matrix(sqldf("select distinct AGEP from acs"))
unique <- as.matrix(unique(acs$AGEP))

for (i in 1:dim(unique)[1]){
  if (unique[i]!=query[i]){
    print(unique[i])
    print(query[i])
  }
}


identical(query, unique)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there is attributes for `dimnames` in 'query' which is not found in 'unique'.  For `identical` to return `TRUE`, everything should be the same

```
str(unique)
#int [1:91, 1] 43 42 16 14 29 40 15 28 30 4 ...
str(query)
# int [1:91, 1] 43 42 16 14 29 40 15 28 30 4 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ : chr "AGEP"
```

One option would be to use `all.equal` with `check.attributes=FALSE`

```
all.equal(unique, query, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or set the attributes in 'query' for `dimnames` to NULL and then use `identical`

```
attr(query, "dimnames") <- NULL
identical(query, unique)
#[1] TRUE
```